# Don't want to download document in docusign how is not sign in optional signature

Tags: docusignapi

I have set an optional signature on the document in DocuSign. If the user does not sign on that don't want to download it. skip that document.

Comment: no idea what you are asking. I don't see a question. Can you please explain further what it is you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are wondering how to tell if an optional signHere tab has been signed, so that you can take actions such as downloading a document based on that information. The call is documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/
Using the query parameters ?include=tabs,recipients will get you the information you need.
In the response a signed tab will have status=signed. An unsigned tab will not have a status property. This is an example response of an unsigned tab.

```
    {
        "stampType": "signature",
        "name": "SignHere",
        "tabLabel": "OptionalSignature",
        "scaleValue": "1",
        "optional": "true",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "92481498",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "358",
        "yPosition": "234",
        "tabId": "56c1716c-843d-47e2-ac45-dde349e1ac88",
        "tabType": "signhereoptional"
    },
```